# Eclipse Che does not start: 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager'

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, docker, eclipse-che

I'm trying to run Eclipse Che (latest beta-13 version) on Windows 7 x64, running the script *che.bat* as:

`> che run -p:9010`

but it fails when it's trying to start the tomcat server:

```
Could not load Logmanager "org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManag
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:3
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:195)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:181)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.util.ClassLogger.<init>(ClassLogger.jav
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.<clinit>(Conne
ap.java:814)
        at sun.management.Agent.startLocalManagementAgent(Agent.java:
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:260)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:447)
Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal Files.Eclipse
```

Any keypoints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug in the beta due to spaces in the directories of Windows paths.  You can:
1. Either download the nightly from eclipse.org/che (which has a fix), or:
2. Move the Eclipse Che installation to a directory that does not have any directories.

Please post any buggs at github.com/codenvy/che and you'll get some help from engineers

Answer (score 1):

I've used a third approach, editing the *setenv.sh* file in *tomcat\bin* folder under eclipse che installation.

It was:

```
#Tomcat options
[ -z "${CATALINA_OPTS}" ]  && CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote  \
                                             -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
                                             -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
                                             -Dche.local.conf.dir=${CHE_LOCAL_CONF_DIR} \
                                             -Dche.home=${CHE_HOME} \
                                             -Dche.logs.dir=${CHE_LOGS_DIR}"
```

With the quoted env. vars:

```
#Tomcat options
[ -z "${CATALINA_OPTS}" ]  && CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote  \
                                             -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
                                             -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
                                             -Dche.local.conf.dir="\"${CHE_LOCAL_CONF_DIR}\"" \
                                             -Dche.home="\"${CHE_HOME}\"" \
                                             -Dche.logs.dir="\"${CHE_LOGS_DIR}\"""
```

And now it works.